# jump page hyperlink not working.

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm using hyperlinks to jump the page as well as shift page on my webpage.

I'm having difficulty getting my hyperlinks to work. I can't figure out why.

I use the following code to shift page

```
<a href="secondpage.html">secondpage</a>
```

and the following code to jump page

```
<a href="#!">jumppagedownwards</a>
```

(further down the page)

```
<a href="!"></a>
```

---

How do I combine my jumppage and my shift page in one hyperlink?

I tried the followingcode:

```
<a href="secondpage.html#!">secondpagefurtherdown</a>
```

For some reason it was working on some links and others it only shift page without jumping.

Is there a better way to write the link?

Comment: I would never expect `!` to be a valid anchor name. If it is valid, then you need `<a name="!"></a>`. But why not `<p id="furtherdownthepage">Start here...</p>`  and have  `<a href="secondpage.html#furtherdownthepage"...`

Answer (score 0):

**Anchors and basic html usage:**

```css
.first-content{
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:grey;
}
.second-content{
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:green;
}
div{
margin-bottom:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-content">
  <a href="#second" name="first">go to second content</a>
</div>
<div class="second-content">
  <a href="#first" name="second">go to first content</a>
</div>
```

If you want to use advanced smooth scoll, you can see this document

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

And you can visit **[50 Best Smooth Scroll jQuery Plugins Of 2017](https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/Best-Smooth-Scroll-jQuery-Plugins.html)**

Comment: Since a long while, IDs are used instead of named anchors

Answer (score -2):

You should try somethink like this:
`<a href="http://www.mylink.html">link</a>` (external url) or
`<a href="./mylink.html">link</a>` (local)

Comment: No he shouldn't. That is not the question. The question is about anchors

Comment: Then the title of the post is wrong, not my answer

Comment: No. He wants to jump to a specific point in a page. Very clear - even without the usage of the word anchor